# Cant remove index or rename table PHPmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I'm trying to create a basic university database outline for an assignment using phpmyadmin. In one of my tables i named a primary key "Student ID". Now when doing queries i get an error,stating "unknow column Student" when i insert the column name Student ID,because of the space in the column name. But phpmyadmin wont let me rename the column or even drop it. It gives this error when trying to rename it or drop it -   "#1025 error of rename of ... to ... errno: 150." I have removed it as a primary key, and am assuming that it wont let me change the  column because of the indexes i mistakenly placed on it. And now it wont let me drop the index using DROP INDEX.

```
ALTER TABLE grade_student_module DROP INDEX Student ID_3
```

This gives me a 1064 error in mysql synthax near ID_3

When i went in to show index from grade_student_module Student ID_3 was listed as an index under the key column.

Essentially i am trying to find a way to remove all indexes and constraints and keys from the table to remove a single space so i can perform simple queries on the tables. Is there any way to do this aside from DROP INDEX which isint working?? Is the reason i am not allowed to drop the index because there is a space in the index name itself?

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't include spaces in table, column or constraint names. But when you do you have to reference them in any statement surrounded by backticks.

```
ALTER TABLE grade_student_module DROP INDEX `Student ID_3`
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly. Would upvote but dont hav the rep:(.